# PHP Timestamp if before noon

Tags: php

I'm trying to print a specific mesasge to the browser depending if my timestamp is AM or PM. In this instance if it's before 12 noon then then I want to echo out Good morning.

The time stamp held in $person['StartDateTime'] is 2019-10-09T14:00:00

The message always prints out the good morning message and I've tried the other posts on here but can't seem to get it to work. I've tried 'noon', 12, 12 PM, etc..

```
if ($person['StartDateTime'] < strtotime("noon"))
    {
    echo 'Meeting Time:' . $person['StartDateTime'] . '<br>';
    echo "Good morning" . '<br>';
    }
```

Edited:

If I try as suggested below I get nothing back.

```
if (strtotime($person['StartDateTime']) < strtotime("noon"))
```

If I try using after >

```
if (strtotime($person['StartDateTime']) > strtotime("noon"))
```

I get the message but also on my morning timestamp -  2019-10-09T10:00:00 which I shouldn't.

I'm wondering do I need to specify noon for the day of the timestamp?

Comment: `if (strtotime($person['StartDateTime']) < strtotime("noon"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after trying a few things the solution in this case was simple.

Format the date using only "A", this will return AP or PM depending on the time.

```
$starttime = date("A",strtotime(date($person['StartDateTime'])));

if ($starttime == "AM"){
echo "Good Morning" . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Datetime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) with proper [format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) argument `a` which gives either am or pm depending on the time

```
if ((new Datetime($person['StartDateTime']))->format('a') == 'am') {
  // am
} else {
  // pm
}
```

Comment: I'm getting - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Answer (score 0):

strtotime return timestamp. You compare int value with string. [Read about strtotime function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)